# how to set an image link into dynamic list correctly in oracle apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Good day, I have created a dynamic list where I passed the image link as per previous posts here.
However, the card will not display the image and the query is:

```
   SELECT NULL,
   COURSE_NAME label, 
   'f?p=&APP_ID.:502:'||:APP_SESSION as target, 
   'YES' is_current, 
   '#APP_IMAGES#abcd.jpg' IMG_PATH, 
   'width="20" height="20"' IMAGE_ATTRIBUTE, 
   COURSE_NAME image_alt
   FROM LS_COURSES
   ORDER BY COURSE_NAME
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a Card Region?

Comment: @Akil_Ramesh yes

Answer (score 0):

Use the below alias name for the columns in your SQL

```
select CARD_PRIMARY_KEY,
       CARD_TITLE,
       CARD_SUBTITLE,
       CARD_BODY,
       CARD_SECONDARY_BODY,
       CARD_ICON,
       CARD_BADGE,
       CARD_IMAGE
  from YOUR_TABLE
```

Then go to the attributes section of the region and map the required columns.
There is an option to do advanced formatting. You can provide the required formatting(width, height etc..) there.
To use the column inside the advanced formatting, use &COLUMN_NAME. as the substution.

Please visit this link for more information
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/a-simple-guide-to-the-new-cards-region-in-apex-202